# What is a good pattern in NodeJS for handling an error response and trying the same call again whilst avoiding callback soup?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am looking for a good pattern for dealing with the following scenario. And, I want to know if this is something that promises would help with?

**Scenario**:

There is a call that returns a callback. That callback get's passed an error object. I want to examine that error object, take an appropriate action to resolve it, and make the original call again. And, I want to avoid the callback soup that my current implementation has.

**(bad) Javascript Example**:

```
doSomethingInteresting(arg0, arg1, function(err, result) {
    if(err && err.code == 1111) {
        fixTheError(err, function() {
            doSomethingInteresting(arg0, arg1, function(err, result) {
                if(err && err.code == 2222) fixTheError(err, function() {
                    // on and on for each possible error scenario...
                });
            });
        });
    }
    // do other stuff...
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is to set things up to run recursively.

```
function callbackFunction (err, arg0, arg1) {
    //If we pass arg0, arg1, and this along with our fix error condition, instead of 
    //making it dependent on the closure, we can make things happen recursively!
    if (err) fixAnyErrorCondition(err, arg0, arg1)
}

//Now make your fix error condition, handle any potential error.
function fixAnyErrorCondition(err, arg0, arg1) {
    if (err.condition1) {
         //fix condition1
    } else if (err.condition2) {
         //fix condition2
    }
    //Once we fix the error conditions, call the function again, using the same arguments!
    doSomethingInteresting(arg0, arg1, callbackFunction);
}

//Now just start the process!
doSomethingInteresting(arg0, arg1, callbackFunction);
```

Using this logic, the doSomethingINteresting function, and your error callbacks will call each other as many times as necessary, without you having to nest a potentially infinite number of callbacks.  YUCH!

Comment: And, of course, you could add a counter to ensure you're not entering an endless cycle and stop trying after X attempts.

Answer (score 1):

There is something called the `Promise` pattern, it is a way to emulate synchronus behavior in async.

For example, traditionally with the callback method one would write code such as this:

```
asyncCall(function(err, data1){
    if(err) return callback(err);       
    anotherAsyncCall(function(err2, data2){
        if(err2) return calllback(err2);
        oneMoreAsyncCall(function(err3, data3){
            if(err3) return callback(err3);
            // are we done yet?
        });
    });
});
```

However using the Promises pattern, one would write:

```
    asyncCall()
.then(function(data1){
    // do something...
    return anotherAsyncCall();
})
.then(function(data2){
    // do something...  
    return oneMoreAsyncCall();    
})
.then(function(data3){
   // the third and final async response
})
.fail(function(err) {
   // handle any error resulting from any of the above calls    
})
.done();
```

Both code examples were taken from [i2devs](http://12devs.co.uk/articles/promises-an-alternative-way-to-approach-asynchronous-javascript/). For more information just search for Promise Javascript Pattern. It is too large to include here.

**Note**: In terms of error handling, with the Promise pattern, if an error is thrown it is carried all the way to the `.fail()` method as you can see in the second example, just as you would expect in normal try/catch routines.

For Promise pattern libraries I would suggest [Q](https://github.com/kriskowal/q) or [bluebird](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird)